# How can I pass a boolean parameter to another component?

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to pass true/false in another component. The user has the possibility to add languages(max2). When the user adds 2 same languages, the validation error will be shown, which to do that I have used `some()` method which returns true or false.
I tried it with ```localStorge``, but it didn't work.

```
import React from "react";

export default class AddLanguage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      message: "",
      items: [],
      hasError: ""
    };
  }

  updateMessage(event) {
    this.setState({
      message: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    var items = this.state.items;

    items.push(this.state.message);

    this.setState({
      items: items,
      message: ""
    });
  }

  handleItemChanged(i, event) {
    const items = event.target.value;
    console.log("items", items);

    this.setState((prev) => {
      const currList = prev.items;
      console.log("currList", currList);

      const isDuplicate = currList.some(
        (lang, idx) => idx !== i && lang) === items
      );

      if (isDupliacte) {
        return { ...prev, hasError: "A BIG ERROR" };
      } else {
        currList[i] = items;
        return { ...prev, items: currList };
      }
    });
  }

  handleItemDeleted(i) {
    var items = this.state.items;

    items.splice(i, 1);

    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
  }

  renderRows() {
    var context = this;

    return this.state.items.map(function (o, i) {
      return (
        <tr key={"item-" + i}>
          <td>
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={o}
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={context.handleItemChanged.bind(context, i)}
              />
            </div>

            {this.state.hasError && (
              <div>
                <label></label>
                <div>
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="inline-block mr-2 h-5 w-5"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  >
                  </svg>{" "}
                  {this.state.hasError}
                  {""}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </td>
          <td >
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={context.handleItemDeleted.bind(context, i)}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }, this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <table>
            <thead">
              <tr>
                <th
                >
                  Button
                </th>
                <th
                >
                  Info
                </th>
                <th
                >
                  ACTION
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.renderRows()}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            className="btn-main"
            disabled={this.state.items.length >= 2}
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          >
            <PlusSmIcon />
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I want to pass to the other component is `isDuplicate` (which might be `true`/`false` to another component.

Comment: You can just add the isDuplicate variable into your component's state, then pass it down to any child component as props - <ChildComponent isDuplicate={this.state.isDuplicate}/> , then isDuplicate would be available in ChildComponent as this.props.isDuplicate

Comment: @Ross in this case I have to pass it to the parent component. The parent component is a functional component

Comment: Ah ok, then yes localStorage is a possibility, or you may have to reach for something like React Context - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html